# Passing a control from another thread as a method parameter on other thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have async operation, in which I call a non-void method:

```
var result = _controller.SendInvoice(this.ParentForm);
```

I was getting error **"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'ParentForm' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on"**

I've managed to fix it by writing code like this:

```
ParentForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { _controller.SendInvoice(ParentForm); }));
```

The problem is that I have to get the return result of the method SendInvoice, but the "solution" above does not solving it for me because it doesn't return value from SendInvoice() method.

Comment: Try `var result = ParentForm.Invoke(() => _controller.SendInvoice(ParentForm));`. The MethodInvoker delegate does not support return values.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to send only data not all form.
Create type `Invoice` and copy data from form to it, and send it to your method.

```
Invoice invoice;
//Here copy data
_controller.SendInvoice(invoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in .Net Framework, you cannot access `ParentForm` from a non-UI thread (exactly the thread the form is created), but you can call `Invoke` on the control. This method is also able to return a value.

```
var result = (RETURN-TYPE)_controller.Invoke(
    new Func<RETURN-TYPE>(() => _controller.SendInvoice(ParentForm)));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I have "specific" controller class, where Invoke is protected and it HAVE to stay like this. Thanks though